# MySQL can not start the server

Tags: mysql, windows, startup, oserror

When starting MySQL server it crashes, there is full log:

```
2021-08-16T11:49:20.983309Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] c:\openserver\modules\database\MySQL-8.0-Win10\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.24) starting as process 9160
2021-08-16T11:49:21.044642Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-08-16T11:50:11.932767Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012611] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation.
2021-08-16T11:50:11.934157Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File (unknown): 'flush' returned OS error 1217. Cannot continue operation
2021-08-16T11:50:11.934525Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

After countless google pages i did not find a solution...and this log is "very" informative, so no useful information about error from this...
also according to MSDN:

```
ERROR_INVALID_MESSAGENAME

1217 (0x4C1)

The format of the specified message name is invalid.
```

also not very useful...
What i tried:

1. Delete log files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ib_logfile101)
2. Delete tmp file (ibtmp1)
3. Reinstall MySQL server
4. Try every value of innodb_force_recovery parameter from 1 to 6
5. Check permissions of MySQL folder and all of its file for write and read
6. Run chkdsk /F /R, rebooting computer and repeating all of the above

I`m running Windows 10 Home 20H2

Comment: the error 1117 could be related to hardware issue or issue related to firmware update check this one https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,50421,50421#msg-50421
for error 1217 check this and the replay https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,591963,591963#msg-591963

Comment: i\`m pretty sure that 24Gb is enough space on disk...and i think my disk is not failing...i didn\`t update anything recently, at least i dont saw any prompts for updating...maybe windows auto-updated idk anyway i dont really think this may be an issue...and i dont want to unnecessary downgrade to check this theory...

Comment: are you able to use the mysqlcheck 
please read this carefully https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html
it's for mysql 8 
and for 5.7 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html

it's tool to check the database or table it come with the server

Comment: mysqlcheck need to be run with sql server running...not my case unfortunately, server just doesn\`t run..innodb_force_recovery isn\`t helping

Comment: while you waiting here try to create post on mysql fourm https://forums.mysql.com/ also and see is someone has a solution there

Comment: You may find this of value - https://www.errorvault.com/en/troubleshooting/runtime-errors/microsoft/windows/error-1117_windows-error-code-1117  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my 7yr old HDD, replaced it with new one and everything works now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).